# PHP Session / Login Script Issue

Tags: php

I'm having an issue getting my login scrip to work correctly. My checkLogin() function seems to work correctly when i run it with the session code (if/else) block commented out. No matter what I do, the code always sends the user to the login page.

```
session_start();

require_once('config/class.Config.php');

if( isset($_POST['login-email'] )&& isset($_POST['login-pass']))
{
        if ( checkLogin($_POST['login-email'], $_POST['login-pass']) == true)
        {
                $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['login-email'];
                header( "Location: members.php" );
        } else {
                header( "Location: login.php" );
        }
} else {
        header( "Location: login.php" );
}


//Uncomment line below to test checkLogin by itself - comment out if/else block above.
//$test = checkLogin($_POST['login-email'], $_POST['login-password']);

var_dump($test);

function checkLogin($email, $password)
{

    $password = sha1($password);
    //echo $password;
    $DBH = Config::getPDOconnection();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=:email AND password=:password ";
    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $STH->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $STH->execute();

    if($STH->rowCount() == 1) {
            return true;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

SOLUTION

in this block:

```
if ( checkLogin($_POST['login-email'], $_POST['login-pass']) == true)
{
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['login-email'];
        header( "Location: members.php" );
} else {
        header( "Location: login.php" );
}
```

the $_POST['login-pass'] should have been $_POST['login-password']

I'm an idiot.

Comment: What values are stored in `$_POST` after submission? Try outputting the array using: `echo"<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>";`

Comment: The correct values are in the post it seems... or at least the values that I entered in the form.

Comment: It sounds like `checkLogin()` is returning false. What is the value of  `$STH->rowCount()`?

Comment: I just tested the function by itself (with the if/else block commented out). The value of $STH->rowCount() is 1

Comment: So, `rowCount()` returns "1", `checkLogin()` returns "true", and yet you are still redirected to "login.php"? Try replacing the `header()` redirects with meaningful `echo` statements, just for troubleshooting purposes. It might help determine where you are being redirected.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. Looks like you found a typo! Nice catch.